# A proper monadic flatMap operation for spark datasets?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm looking for a function with the following signature:

```
bind[A, B](f: A => Dataset[B], ds: Dataset[A]): Dataset[A]
```

Is there such a thing in the spark library? (`flatMap` unfortunately requires a mapping from `A` to `TraversableOnce[B]`, which means I have to concreteize my dataset, unless I'm missing something).
If not, how would one go about implementing such a function?

Comment: What is it supposed to do what an `A => TraversableOnce[B]` doesn't do already?

Comment: Mapping without concretizing the dataset to a TravesableOnce.

Comment: I do not think it can be made to work, because Spark in general does not support calling/creating RDDs inside of RDD operations. Any flavour of `rdd.map(element => otherRDD.whatever)` has no sense, under the Spark execution model (although it can "conceptually" make sense). RDDs are not collections (sure, in bird's eye view, they look like so, and it's easy to grasp their essence that way), they are a distributed computing enabling variant of them.

Comment: `def flatMap[U](func: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U])` is defined as such because you're actually working on a *subset* of the `DataSet[T]`, not the entire data set. This is, as others said, because of the way Spark internally partitions the data so each worker gets a chunk. Thus, returning a `Dataset[B]` doesn't make sense as we're only operating on a subset. `Dataset[A]` doesn't obey the monad laws, thus it isn't a monad.

Comment: I fundamentally don't understand why you want an `f: A => Dataset[B]` in the first place. As soon as you assume that you are working with one huge homogeneous blob of data that fits into a `Dataset[A]`, you don't need to care about mapping it using an `f: A => Dataset[B]`, because it would violate the assumption that you are working with a huge homogeneous blob of disconnected data records in the first place. As soon as you want to have it monadic, you probably do not want a `Dataset` in the first place. Could you describe in more detail why you would want a framework that is monadic?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin *"because it would violate the assumption that you are working with a huge homogeneous blob of disconnected data records"* I'm not sure I follow. Why does `A => Dataset[B]` imply such an assumption?

Comment: @Gal Why do you need to "concretize" (I assume you mean collect) a dataset?  `flatMap` with it's `A => TraversableOnce[B]` operation works entirely as a distributed dataset operation.  The othen place you would have a problem is if the function used some external dataset not shown here.  In that case, you should use operations like join and union to combine them instead.

Comment: @puhlen because the output of `f` is too large to fit into memory, so I can't collect it.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The only *real* difference that I see between a `TraversableOnce` and `Dataset` is that a `TraversableOnce` represents a collection of elements in the memory of a single machine, whereas `Dataset` represents a collection of elements distributed across multiple machines. If one all of a sudden begins to care how this collection is distributed (or not distributed) across multiple nodes for reasons other than performance, then it means that one somehow sees the "dataset" as something that is more than a loose union of its constituents. But is it still "just" a dataset then?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin But we do care about datasets being distributed. That's why we use datasets and not plain collections to begin with.

Comment: @Gal If the collection `f(a)` doesn't fit into the memory of a single node for a single element `a` from the original dataset `ds: Dataset[A]`, but you assume that `bind(f, ds)` fits into memory, then it means that `ds` has approximately as many (or fewer) elements as there are nodes. Why don't you simply collect the `ds` on the master node, build the dataset `f(a)` for all `a <- ds`, and then take the union of the generated datasets?

Comment: @Gal, is it possible to have f produce it's output lazily, ie. in an iterator?  That should prevent the need to have the entire result in memory at once.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Why won't bind fit into memory? It's a function that generates an uncollected dataset from a single element. The collection is delayed until the output flattened Dataset is collected.

Comment: @puhlen It's possible if I can convert the Dataset to a lazy Iterator, but at that point in time I assume my performance will go to hell since my tasks/nodes are no longer distributed.

Comment: @Gal, you don't need to convert the dataset into anything, keep it as a distributed dataset, I'm only talking about your function inside of the flatmap operation (which is a dataset operation and runs distributed on the cluster)

Comment: @puhlen Unfortunately not, since the data I need would be built from some other `Dataset`.

Comment: @Gal, then use join and/or union to combine your datasets.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I'm actually kind of confused regarding this entire conversation. Not sure what we're discussing anymore? :)

Comment: @puhlen I solved it by collecting the original `Dataset` (i.e., `ds` in my method signature). It should work, but I would still prefer a proper monadic solution since I really like monads. `union` would also probably work but wasn't needed.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I did end up collecting `ds`, I just don't particularly care for that solution.

Comment: *"I would still prefer a proper monadic solution since I really like monads."* But a `Dataset[A]` is not a monad.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov But I really wish it were. As far as can I tell, it's an implementation/architectural design detail, not a fundamental reason. There is no mathematical reason I can see why a distributed dataset couldn't be monadic.

Comment: @Gal well, yes, it's a design "detail". But quite a significant one, you can't change it that easily. But indeed, there is no *mathematical* reason why a distributed dataset couldn't be monadic.

Comment: As a Spark newbie, I wasn't aware of all those details when I asked the question. I have learnt a lot about it from these comments and answers, so a great many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RDD` is not a monad. 
`RDD` object makes sense only on a driver and `map/flatmap` functions are performed on workers. So you can't emit `RDD`s in map/flatmap operations.

`Dataset` is a facade to `RDD` so I guess it's impossible as well.

Comment: I mean, you technically *can* emit an `RDD` (or a `Dataset`), since you can convert a `Seq` to a `Dataset`, but that requires generating a concrete sequence to begin with. Although, I'm not sure a `Dataset` has an `Encoder`, so maybe that won't compile...

Comment: @Gal You can convert `Seq` to a `Dataset` *in what spark context*? There is no spark context on worker nodes.

Comment: @Gal Technically you cannot. Theoretically you can (it will compile), but it is not valid in the Spark execution model, and typically will either fail on runtime, or deadlock. There is more than types to consider here.

Comment: Well that sucks :\

Comment: @Gal : in a sense. You may lose some "type purity" in terms of functionnal programming composability. But this limitation makes sense. The driver can create arbitrarily large collections, and access them lazyly as datasets. The workers have to work inside their own memory space, and never outgrow it : they should not have to create datasets (other arbitrarily large "collections").

Comment: @Gal I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. A user is not supposed to override/implement RDDs and Datasets. It should use existing ones. So you can't have a custom way to lift your collections into a Dataset of RDD.

Comment: @GPI I understand the limitation, unfortunately my datasets are very large.

Comment: @simpadjo I don't want to lift a collection. That's why I said I accept a function of type `A => Dataset[B]` and not `A => TravesableOnce[B]`. I just gave it as (evidently erroneous) example.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you have `N` nodes, with `M` memory on each node.
Furthermore, assume that `f(a)` is roughly of same size for all `a <- ds`.
You say that you want `f(a)` to be a distributed `Dataset`. The only reason why you would insist on `f` returning a `Dataset` is that the returned value doesn't fit into memory on a single node, thus

```
|f(a)| >= M .
```

At the same time you assume that `bind(f, ds)` will fit into memory, thus

```
N * M >= ds.size * |f(a)| >= ds.size * M
```

If we cancel `M`, then it says:

```
N >= ds.size
```

that is, the number of elements in `ds` must be relatively small (smaller than the number of compute nodes). This in turn means that you can simply collect it on the master node, map it to dataset, and then take the union. Something along these lines (untested):

```
def bind[A, B](f: A => Dataset[B], ds: Dataset[A]): Dataset[A] = {
  ds.collect.map(f).reduce(_ union _)
}
```

Trying to make it into a general monad does not make much sense, because if you read `Dataset` as "huge distributed dataset that barely fits into a huge cluster with multiple nodes", then

- `ds` is already huge
- each `f(a)` is huge
- `ds.flatMap(f)` is huge to the power of two, doesn't fit into memory

Thus, a general `bind` can be:

- impossible, because result doesn't fit into memory.
- replaced by `fold(f: A => TraversableOnce[B])`, because `f(a)` is small
- replaced by `ds.collect`, because `ds` is small

And you are the one who has to make the decision "what is small" in each particular case. That's probably the reason why no generic `flatMap(f: A => Dataset[B])` is provided: there is nontrivial design decision that has to be made in every invocation of such `flatMap`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `bind(f, ds)` has practically zero memory consumption, since nothing is collected. It takes no more memory than `map` or `filter` or `flatMap`. `f` is a function that creates an uncollected `Dataset` object (otherwise it wouldn't be a `Dataset`).

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't understand why N * M should be larger than anything. It can work iteratively with fewer nodes if it needs to.

Comment: @Gal The "`bind(f, ds)` has practically zero memory consumption" looks a bit like a reference to the lazily evaluated execution plan composed from `map`s and `filter`s. But once you force spark to evaluate everything and cache it in RAM, then it will certainly take up some significant amounts of memory. I'm not sure how it then can "work iteratively"? Should it evict parts of dataset from memory and recompute them all the time? Well, if it should do this, then you have to take responsibility for that by explicitly coding it. I'm not sure whether that would be an intuitive default behavior?

Comment: It is indeed a reference to lazily evaluation execution plan, which is why I'm returning a lazily evaluated `Dataset`. Ideally, spark will eventually evaluate `Dataset[B]`, and treat it as any other `Dataset`. The creation of the Dataset in the bind operation doesn't need to take any additional memory than creating any other `Dataset`, which is usually done locally at a single Driver anyway (Assuming I'm getting my terminology correct).

Comment: As for the memory: I suppose it depends on what kind of collection you are doing. If it can partition the data in such a way that not all of it has to be held in (distributed) memory at the same time, then I don't see a problem.